# Performing DataFlow using ADO NET

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I have a stored procedure which has only one parameter @DATE in SQL Server that forms a data set that I need. This data set needs to be transferred to MySQL table on a regular basis. Can this be performed using ADO NET and how do I pass a procedure in a dataflow operation with a parameter using ADO NET SQL Server TO MySQL data export?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an ADO.NEt source? Try an OLEDB source and select your stored procedure name in the source. Set the parameter in an SSIS variable and pass it to the stored procedure. the output fields of the SP will prove as a source to your MYSQL database.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Have not tested out the data export itself. Will do that on Monday, but data truncate works. SSIS truncates the data that was in MySQL so i assume  that the data export will work as well

Comment: Error: 0xC020844B at Data Flow Task, ADO NET Destination [196]: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.0.30-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Comment: Do you have any sql syntax being used/generated?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2009/01/07/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis/ check this out..

Comment: Figured out the solution on my own. The best scenario is to just provide SET SESSION sql_mode= 'ansi'; in ODBC Settings.

Comment: Great.. will note it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Provided the following SET SESSION sql_mode= 'ansi'; in ODBC  Connection paragraph Initial Statement field.